# emacs and mysql on windows 7

Tags: mysql, emacs24

I have been using emacs for writing programs and recently I want to execute SQL queries through it , I run the following commands and get the following error:

```
M-x sql-Mysql
```

then I just press <kbd>return</kbd> and then

```
user:
password:
database:
server:
```

and I get the error

```
" unable to locate sql program mysql "
```

I have searched for two continuous days and got the suggestions to edit .emacs file but of no use. I am using windows 7.

My init file looks like this :

```
(setq sql-connection-alist
'((pool-a
(sql-product 'mysql)
(sql-server "1.2.3.4")
(sql-user "me")
(sql-password "mypassword")
(sql-database "thedb")
(sql-port 3306))
(pool-b
(sql-product 'mysql)
(sql-server "1.2.3.4")
(sql-user "me")
(sql-password "mypassword")
(sql-database "thedb")
(sql-port 3307))))

(defun sql-connect-preset (name)
  "Connect to a predefined SQL connection listed in `sql-connection-alist'"
  (eval `(let ,(cdr (assoc name sql-connection-alist))
    (flet ((sql-get-login (&rest what)))
      (sql-product-interactive sql-product)))))

(defun sql-pool-a ()
  (interactive)
  (sql-connect-preset 'pool-a))
```

Comment: hello there, i found the servername and username using \s command on mysql cmd window but now i get the error -- process sql exited abnormally with code 1

Comment: hello is any body there ...... is anyone listening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well,i think,it does not need to put that code in my init file so i erased all that.in fact i need not put any thing in the init file for mysql to run.i just filled in the appropriate details in the following fields:

> **user**:root
>
> **password**:which i have created during mysql installation
>
> **database**:i left this field blank
>
> **server**:localhost

then no problem occurred and i could run the sql commands as usual as i would in a normal mysql command window.what i made out from it that server as 'localhost' and user as 'root' are the main parameters and should work in probably all the cases(if you are running mysql server on your system through emacs. password to be filled is the password entered during the time of installation.